# How do I sum over specific number of columns in dataframe in R?

Tags: r, loops, split

I have a dataframe (cenMca) with 1020 rows and 800 columns.

Each 4 columns, I have a set of data I call "cen". So, from column 1 to 4, I have cen 1, from 5 to 8, I have cen2 and so on.

I wanted to split cenMca into 200 hundred smaller dataframes of dimensions equal to 1020 lines by 4 columns and sum the values per row. For this I'd `apply` a function sum to each row, however,  I searched for ways to split my dataframe in the way I wanted, but failed in doing so. Also, I have no idea how I would iterate through these smaller dataframes to save each with a different name.

So I thought that instead of breaking cenMca into smaller dataframes, I'd sum the values from cenMca and assign them to a single dataframe I called sumvec. So, for every 4 columns in cenMca, I'd have one corresponding column in sumvec. This gives sumvec dimensions equal to 1020 rows and 200 columns.

To accomplish this, I tried:

```
sumvec = matrix(NA,1020,200) 

  for (i in 1:1020 ){
    for (j in seq(1,800,4)){
        sumvec[i,(j+3)/4] = cenMca[i,j]+cenMca[i,j+1]+cenMca[i,j+2]+cenMca[i,j+3]   
    }

  }
```

The first `for` runs through rows, and the second `for` runs through the columns. My increment is 4 for the second `for` because then I'd get all four values I wanted in a cycle.

I know this is far from efficient, but I thought it'd work. 
After I ran the script, I got this: [image]

I tried `warnings()` but nothing came up. All I have in sumvec is "NA"

How could I fix this?
Other techniques on how to get this done will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good application for `rowSums`. You could use `lapply` to run it over the grouped columns like you're trying to do.

I'll use similar data setup as @R.Schifini:

```
set.seed(1)
z <- matrix( rnorm( 1020*800 ), ncol = 800 )
```

Make it a data frame, like your data.

```
z <- as.data.frame(z)
```

Now group the data frame into groups of 4 columns, running `rowSums` on each group.

```
x <- lapply( seq.int( 1, ncol(z), 4 ),
        function(i) {
          rowSums( z[ , i:(i+3) ] )
        } )
```

Bind it together as a single data frame, with the column names you need.

```
x <- as.data.frame( x, col.names = paste0( "cen", seq_along( x ) ) )
```

Here's a small sample of the output.

```
> head( x[1:6] )
        cen1       cen2       cen3       cen4       cen5       cen6
1 -0.8027240 -0.7437158 -1.5305678 -0.7055544  2.0122082  0.7851487
2  0.0854064  0.2422316 -2.5071390  1.7854231 -3.5219698 -0.7699433
3  1.2738387  1.7360087  1.4317099 -3.3501584 -1.8412381 -2.1396324
4 -0.5864149 -0.5648199 -0.3099392 -1.9144969  0.7874474 -2.4840934
5 -0.3887289 -1.0745042 -1.9729363  1.8971846 -4.3374676  2.5744197
6  0.9104741 -0.7546090  4.2516971  1.0335885  2.6814576 -0.2548666
```

Comment: Hey, Rosscova. Thanks for the input. I tried to run your code, though, and every time I hit the lapply block, I got this error: "Error in rowSums(cenMca[, x:(x + 3)]) : 'x' must be numeric". With typeof I saw "x" is character. I tried to substitute x with a 1020*200 matrix but it didn't work.

Comment: That step is within an `lapply` call, such that `x` is the iterator. In other words `x` is all of the values of `seq.int(1,ncol(z),4)`, taken one by one, but only created for and used within `lapply` (you can't really check it's class outside of the `lapply` call, since it doesn't really exist until `lapply` is run). If you're using `x` elsewhere, you can choose a different iterator, for example `...function(i){rowSums(z[,i:(i+3)])}...`.

Comment: Thanks again for your feedback. I made the necessary adjustments and it worked as it should.

Comment: Good to hear! Using `x` as both the iterator and the output was bad form on my part anyway, so I've changed it in the answer as well to make it clearer for others.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

I'll create a sample matrix (also works if it is a data frame)

```
z = matrix(floor(runif(120, 0, 100)), ncol = 12)
> z
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
 [1,]   37   50   37    0   71   84   29   65    0    34    33    65
 [2,]   53   60   17   44   39   94   16   66   72    12    27    32
 [3,]   10   26    5   26   11   58   39   47   71    38    11    19
 [4,]   80   42   65   93   24   50   45   96   18    92     4    11
 [5,]   73   36   57   71   86   18   43   40   64    80    37    99
 [6,]    5   94   98   16   43    0   51   84   54    75    33    37
 [7,]   48   12   60   47   49   87   84   75   33    95    17    56
 [8,]   92    7    6   69   69   13    5   53   63    99    62    73
 [9,]    4   96   16   46   76    2   55   87   82    60    39    87
[10,]   29   44   47   95   15   93   68   46   70     2    95    57
```

Then add columns in groups of four:

```
result = z[,seq(1,12,by = 4)]+z[,seq(2,12,by = 4)]+z[,seq(3,12,by = 4)]+z[,seq(4,12,by = 4)]

> result
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]  124  249  132
 [2,]  174  215  143
 [3,]   67  155  139
 [4,]  280  215  125
 [5,]  237  187  280
 [6,]  213  178  199
 [7,]  167  295  201
 [8,]  174  140  297
 [9,]  162  220  268
[10,]  215  222  224
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to loop over rows. R works well with vectors.

Secondly, NAs in `sumvec` might be results of NAs in `cenMca`. If you have NAs in `cenMca`, use `sum` instead of `+`.

```
for (j in seq(1,800,4)) sumvec[,(j+3)/4] <- apply(cenMca[,j:(j+3)],1,sum, na.rm=T)
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: You'll likely find `rowSums` much more efficient than your `apply(... 1, sum...)` call.

Comment: You're right. I just keep forgeting that `rowSums` works well with data frames too :) Thanks for reminding me.